# How can I navigate to failed Karma tests in WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm, karma-runner

I'm able to run my Karma test suite from within WebStorm, using a Karma Run Configuration. After the tests run, the failed ones are shown in a tree on the left side. I would expect that I could click/double-click on a test name and be taken to the source code for the test, but that doesn't happen.

I'm pretty sure I've seen this work in a video before. How can I turn it on?

I looked at the documentation here but it wasn't very helpful: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/test-runner-tab.html

Answer (score 1):

In Karma tool window click gear icon and check Auto scroll to source.

[image]

Comment: That really seems like it should work... but I have that checked and yet it still does not scroll. It looks like your editor turns the filenames into links, too -- mine doesn't do that. I wonder if that's related to my problem.

Comment: Check that the test folder is included in the project.

Comment: It wasn't -- so I marked the folders containing tests as `Tests` in the `Directories` page in Preferences. That doesn't seem to have any effect. _But_, if I click on the karma source file in the tree, it'll open up that file.